# Small python syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x

```
if n<=1: return 0

for b in bases:
    if n%b==0: return 0

tests,s  = 0L,0
m        = n-1

# turning (n-1) into (2**s) * m
```

it says test,s = OL,0 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

can someone tell me what the problem is? thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a0IO.jpg

whole code: http://pastie.org/private/65twf2meuulduwe9tk6eeq

Comment: Can you edit the question with the proper indentation and without the asterisks so we can test your code? (There is nothing wrong with the line you cite when copy/pasted into a Python interpreter, so something else is going on.)

Comment: Corrected the indent. Please make sure you paste well-formated code, because in Python it matters.

Comment: Some background on what this code is meant to do would be nice

Comment: i posted the whole code and indented

Comment: I copied your code into ideone and it passed syntax check fine: http://ideone.com/uzisz

Comment: The code as listed at pastie.org seems to compile and run for me.  Of course, there are no outputs, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: You have Python 2.x syntax but your interpreter seems to be 3.x...

Comment: is there a way to use this for 3.XX or do I have to uninstall this and install 2.xx?

Comment: @RichardWilliam: You can have Python 2 and Python 3 installed at the same time. But you should use the version your tutorial is made for, or find a tutorial made for the version you use. There are Python 3 tutorials as well.

Answer (score 9):

It is a syntax error in Python3. Just use `0` instead of `0L`

see [pep237](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

try like this..It might solve your problem.

```
test,s=long(0),0
```